# Mutate across - returning values from columns which number is stored in another ones?

Tags: r, dplyr, across, mutate

I have a following dataset with 100 variables Z1 to Z100 containing character values and 10 variables containing column numbers.

| Z1 | ... | Z100 | V1 | ... | V10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | ... | xyz | 56 | ... | NA |

An exemplary dataset - with 5 rows, 5 Z-variables (Z1-Z5) and 3 V-variables (V1-3) and 3 created variables V1_1-V1_3:

```
structure(list(Z1 = c("aaa", NA, "aaa", NA, "aaa", NA, "aaa"), 
    Z2 = c("bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb", NA, "bbb"), Z3 = c("ccc", 
    "ccc", NA, "ccc", "ccc", "ccc", "ccc"), Z4 = c("ddd", "ddd", 
    NA, "ddd", NA, "ddd", "ddd"), Z5 = c("eee", "eee", "eee", 
    "eee", "eee", "eee", NA), V1 = c(1, 3, 4, NA, 2, 2, NA), 
    V2 = c(NA, 3, 3, NA, 5, NA, 1), V3 = c(4, 4, 4, NA, 5, 5, 
    NA), V1_1 = c("aaa", "ccc", NA, NA, "bbb", NA, NA), V2_1 = c(NA, 
    "ccc", NA, NA, "eee", NA, "aaa"), V3_1 = c("ddd", "ddd", 
    NA, NA, "eee", "eee", NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I'd like to create a set of 3 new variables V1_1 to V3_1, where each will contain a character value from a column which number was in original V variable.

Technically one could do the following:

```
dataset %>% mutate(., V1_1 = c_across(1:5)[V1],
...
V3_1 = c_across(1:5)[V3]
)
```

Just not to do it step by step, I've tried the following with across:

```
dataset %>% 
mutate(across(V1:V3, dataset[,.], .names = "{col}_1"))
```

But I got an error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(V1:V3, m3[, .], .names = "{col}_1")`.
Caused by error in `.subset()`:
! invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Comment: Could you provide a little bit of sample data in valid R syntax so it's easy to test solutions? Five Z columns and 2 or 3 V columns would be plenty to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Also, **if** your real data has more than 1 row, please use 2 rows of example data. There might be shortcuts if your input is 1 row that wouldn't generalize well to multirow data.

Comment: @GregorThomas Here is a cloud-based .csv: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wclUb0SRef51hPB58wZ87uO1HJi-fiGH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I don't download files for Stack Overflow questions - takes too long, and often ends up with follow-up questions about column classes and such, and the question isn't a good resource for future users when your link goes stale. Could you please just put a tiny example in the question? If `sample_data` is the name of that data frame you posted in Drive, then `dput(sample_data)` will give R code to replicate it including all class and structure info--just put the `dput()` output directly in your question.

Comment: Now, it's revised!

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

The "tidy" way to approach this problem would be to convert your data to long format with a single `Z` column and maybe a separate data set with a `V` column. But we can skip that by using matrix indexing.

Here, we break apart your data into a `z` matrix and a `v` data frame, and then extract the correct `z` elements easily using a matrix of row and column indices in `[` to pull them out. I used a `_result` suffix so that we can compare with your `_1` suffix and see that the solution worked.

```
z = dataset %>% select(starts_with("Z")) %>% as.matrix
v = dataset %>% select(matches("V[0-9]+$"))
result = lapply(v, \(x) z[cbind(seq_along(x), x)])
names(result) = paste0(names(result), "_result")

dataset %>% cbind(result)
#     Z1   Z2   Z3   Z4   Z5 V1 V2 V3 V1_1 V2_1 V3_1 V1_result V2_result V3_result
# 1  aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  1 NA  4  aaa <NA>  ddd       aaa      <NA>       ddd
# 2 <NA>  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee  3  3  4  ccc  ccc  ddd       ccc       ccc       ddd
# 3  aaa  bbb <NA> <NA>  eee  4  3  4 <NA> <NA> <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
# 4 <NA>  bbb  ccc  ddd  eee NA NA NA <NA> <NA> <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
# 5  aaa  bbb  ccc <NA>  eee  2  5  5  bbb  eee  eee       bbb       eee       eee
# 6 <NA> <NA>  ccc  ddd  eee  2 NA  5 <NA> <NA>  eee      <NA>      <NA>       eee
# 7  aaa  bbb  ccc  ddd <NA> NA  1 NA <NA>  aaa <NA>      <NA>       aaa      <NA>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you :) How would it look like with tidy approach?

Comment: I'll leave that to someone else if they want to tackle it--it seems more of a pain to code ;)